Edit Mode Symmetry Behavior Change?
I had an asymmetrical mesh, which I wanted to be symmetrical in one of it's shape keys. I did this successfully by going into edit mode, enabling x-axis symmetry, and moving one vertex, which caused to mesh to instantly become symmetrical.
I want to do this with a second mesh, but when I enable symmetry and move a vertex this time, only that one vertex moves and the mesh doesn't become symmetrical.
How do I get the symmetry to work they way it did with the first mesh?

I found a work-around:
Enable topology mirror, select all vertices in edit mode, move the mesh a little ways along an axis, and then reset the movement along that axis back to zero in the 'move' box that appears in the bottom left corner. This makes the mesh instantly symmetrical.

Your object is probably not symmetrical anymore, you could symmetrize again (top bar > Mesh > Symmetrize then select the axis in the Operator Box) but you may not want to do it for some reason (and in that case I don't see any easy solution):


Thank you. Unfortunately I don't think symmetrize is an option because it wouldn't work for a shape key. My first mesh was also asymmetrical, yet by moving a vertex with symmetry enabled it immediately made it symmetrical. I don't know why it is behaving differently with my other asymmetrical mesh.
